# How to Generate HTML report from Junit Xml report

Tags: php, ant, junit, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to generate the HTML report from the JUnit Xml report which is generated after the completion of the test execution.

I am using PHP + web driver. I have generated a .xml file using --log-junit .

Then i have written one Target in build.xml file to generate the HTML report for thet xml report.Below is my Target:

```
<target name="junitHTMLreport" description="Create a report for the rest result">
    <echo message="Delete the Junit HTML Directory if exists" />
    <delete dir="${JUnitHTMLReports.dir}" />
    <echo message="Create the Junit HTML Directory" />
    <mkdir dir="${JUnitHTMLReports.dir}"/>
    <junitreport todir="${JUnitHTMLReports.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${JUnitReports.dir}">
    <include name="*.xml"/>
    </fileset>
    <report format="frames" todir="${JUnitHTMLReports.dir}"/>
    </junitreport>
    </target>
```

But my problem is that when i hit my target using ant it generates blank HTML file.

I found that when i delete the root element  and  from my xml and then save that xml and then hit the target using ant. it generates a valid html file.

Do we have any solution to delete the root element at run time so that my ant target pick that xml and generate the HTML run time.

If we can have other other solution to accomplish this. please let me know.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So you should have other targets that actually run the JUnit tests and generate the xml files, and those should be required to run before you run the junitHTTMLreport target.  Something like <target name="junitHTMLreport " depends="run.tests" >

Comment: I guess you are talking about to generate the HTML report at end when all other dependents target has been run. but this is not the exact solution of the asked query.

Comment: My thought was that maybe if none of the xml files were created, that might explain an empty report - no content.   Do you mean that the xml  files with the results have been created but you still get an empty report?

Comment: It might also help to provide more of the ant script (build.xml) with some of the other JUnit related targets.